# The use of the "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" when parsing large html files results in an error

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse a large HTML file using "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser". The code is some thing like that:

```
<?php
    include('/lib/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

    $data_url = "data/data.html";

    $date_html = file_get_html($data_url);
    foreach($date_html->find('li a') as $element){
        $data = $element->href;
        echo $data;
    }
?>
```

Size of "data.html" is about 3MB. Execution of code results in "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\parser\index.php on line 7.

What am i suppose to do?

Comment: `file_get_html()` isn't returning what you think it is. Use `var_dump($date_html);` to see what you're getting.

Comment: 'What am i suppose to do?' - you could try DOMDocument and loadhtml()

Comment: You must have an error and $date_url is null (also should it be datA?)

Comment: file_get_html() is a function in "PHP Simple HTML DOM" library. Actually i think that the error is with find() function.

Comment: _"i think that the error is with find() function"_ No. PHP is clearly telling you that you're trying to invoke a method on a variable that does not contain an object.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a URL on the web or a local file? See my answer...

Comment: I'm trying to parse a local file. local parsing is possible according to "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual".

Comment: Have you confirmed that the size of the file is the problem? If you overwrite data.html with a smaller file, does the problem go away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MAX_FILE_SIZE` defined in `simple_html_dom` to be 600KB.

you can edit this code: `define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);` on `simple_html_dom.php` file.

worked for me

Comment: I changed MAX_FILE_SIZE to define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 6000000); and it worked. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_html` **fails** when attempting to **read the file** `data/data.html`

In this case the returned value that you store in `$date_html` is not an object.
Attenpting later to call the method `find` raises the error you get.

---

**1.**

As you're trying to parse a large file you need to increase the maximum file size allowed by **simplehtmldom** that is set by default at 600.000 bytes (so not enought).

You can do this with `define( 'MAX_FILE_SIZE', 4000000 ); // Max file size 4MB appox.`

**before** you include the library:

```
define( 'MAX_FILE_SIZE', 4000000 ); // Max file size 4MB appox.
include('/lib/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
```

---

**2.**

If adjusting `MAX_FILE_SIZE` doesn't solve the problem then ensure `data/data.html` is the correct **relative** path to the file to be parsed.

If the file is not found the `file_get_html` will fail.

In this case you may try to pass an absolute path (a path that begins with `/`), ex:

`/var/data/data.html`

Comment: I'm trying to parse a local file. local parsing is possible according to "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual".

Comment: @AdelAmani Of course. Then `data/data.html` is not found. Pass an absolute path. I edited the answer

Comment: you mean: "localhost/parser/data/data.html"?

Comment: @AdelAmani you can safely define it **in your code** without modifying `simplehtmldom`. You just need to DEFINE it **before** you include the library. This way if you update the library (overwriting your edit) your code won't break

Comment: you'r right. actually i think overwriting should be after include('/lib/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');. am i wrong?